# Obtain Keycloak Entitlement for signed JWTs

Tags: node.js, jwt, redhat, keycloak, json-web-token

I'm currently implementing a node.js module for Keycloak which uses the [keycloak auth utils](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-nodejs-auth-utils) internally. For fine-grained authorization it should be possible to retrieve the [entitlements](http://www.keycloak.org/docs/2.4/authorization_services_guide/topics/service/entitlement/entitlement-api-aapi.html). This works like a charm for "clientId + clientSecret" JWTs.

Additionally it should be possible to retrieve those entitlements for [signed JWTs](https://keycloak.gitbooks.io/documentation/securing_apps/topics/oidc/java/client-authentication.html). When upload the key to my keycloak instance and sign the JWT with the private Key, it validates successfully with the help of the server and the stored public key. So the signed JWT is definitely valid (of course I changed the client's authenticator).

The issue is:
When I pass the signed JWT to the entitlement endpoint I get the following error:

```
{
  "error": "invalid_bearer_token",
  "error_description": "Could not obtain bearer access_token from request."
}
```

The request:

```
curl -k  -L -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Authorization: bearer <signed_jwt>' '<realm_url>/authz/entitlement/foobar'
```

Now the question:
Is it possible to retrieve entitlements for signed JWTs and if yes, how?
What's my fault?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to include the `kid` header while signing the token.